# Cordova Local Notification Repeat after firstAt

Tags: cordova, notifications, cordova-plugins

Cordova plugin notification local to trigger every day after first date is reached

```
cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
     id: id,
     title: title,
     message: message,
     firstAt: schedule_date_time,
     every: 'day',
     // sound:true,
      actions: [
              { id: 'yes', title: 'TAKE ACTION' }

            ]
 });
```

I want the notification to trigger every day but only when the firstAt date is reached. So the notification works on the firstAt date and continues to trigger once every day till the user take an ACTION

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the `trigger` config to achieve the same. More info [here](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications#repeating)

```
cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
  id: id,
  title: title,
  message: message,
  // sound:true,
  actions: [{
      id: 'yes',
      title: 'TAKE ACTION'
    }
  ]
  trigger: {
    at: schedule_date_time
  }
});
```

> There is a bit ambiguity around how to exactly set the
>   trigger config and what the 'count' exactly does, but this is surely
>   the starting point to your final solution.

Comment: I have upgraded to 0.9.0-beta.3. I want the first trigger to occur at a certain date then repeat itself every day starting from the following day